# Unity jump from one canvas scene to another scene with canvas

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine

I want to jump from one canvas scene to another scene with canvas in unity but i keep getting this warning

Multiple EventSystems in scene... this is not supported
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:OnEnable()

how do i solve this ??

Comment: I don't think we can help without your Canvas code. You need to provide this.

Comment: Do you have multiple EventSystems in your scene? I'd recommend removing the excess, as the error says. Are you loading Canvas prefabs? Remove the EventSystem from the prefabs and add 1 to the scene.

Comment: if you load the scene with additive param it gives you the warning.